# How do I make my OpenGL Layer transparent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I am trying to draw a completely transparent rectangle on a green background.  The transparent rectangle is on its own EAGLLayer ( which is in a UIView ). The background layer is a part of a cocos-2d view. The code where I clear out the EAGLLayer is as follows:

```
    glClearColor(clearColor.x, clearColor.y, clearColor.z, 0.0f/*clearColor.w*/);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //dont f-word touch this unless you have a very good reason
    //if you do f-word with this, reprofile the ios version with the opengl analyzer
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glClearDepthf(0);
    glClearStencil( 0 );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I also printed out the open gl blend state so you can see them:

```
    GLint srcRGB;
    GLint srcAlpha;
    GLint dstRGB;
    GLint dstAlpha ;
    glGetIntegerv( GL_BLEND_SRC_RGB, &srcRGB );
    glGetIntegerv( GL_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA, &srcAlpha );
    glGetIntegerv( GL_BLEND_DST_RGB, &dstRGB );
    glGetIntegerv( GL_BLEND_DST_ALPHA, &dstAlpha );

    printf("src rgb: %x, src alpha: %x dst rgb: %x, dst alpha:  %x\n", srcRGB, srcAlpha, dstRGB, dstAlpha);

    // PRINTS:  src rgb: 302, src alpha: 1 dst rgb: 303, dst alpha:  1
    // ( 0x302 is GL_SRC_ALPHA, and 0x303 is GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA )
```

I expect the centered rectangle to be invisible, but instead it is a light shade of green, like this:
[image: How my view looks]
If I change that background color to red, the inner rectangle becomes a light shade of red.  So the alpha blending is working, its just not working enough.

Any suggestions about how to debug this?

Comment: You could discard fragments in the shader if the alpha value is 0.

Comment: what values are clearColor.x/y/z? Did you try setting them to 0? Also, you can simply not render anything which is supposed to be invisible... it's just a waste of processing time if you render them.